# HashMap of HashMap-> output Problems

Tags: java, hashmap, output

Having the following HashMap:
`HashMap <String, HashMap <Integer, ArrayList <Reservation> >>` buffer;
I'm going to output every single value of every single key of the two hashmaps. How can I do?

I have already written this portion of the code:

```
HashMap map=mod.getAllRecords();

for (Object key: map.keySet()) {
    String Date=key.toString();
    Object map2=map.get(key);

    for(Object Key : ??){//<--------------

        
    }
```

Comment: `map.forEach((k, v) -> { System.out.println(k); v.keySet().forEach(System.out::println); });`

Comment: Why are you using `Object` instead of the real type of the `HashMap`'s contents?

Comment: "two hashmaps" seems incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I know is to write three for-loops - first for the key elements themselves which are already strings, second for the integers within the HashMap inside the first HashMap and third for the values inside each array of the second HashMap:

```
    for (String key: map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key);                        //prints the strings
        HashMap <Integer, ArrayList <Reservation> > map2 = map.get(key);

        for(Integer key2 : map2.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key2);                   //prints the integers
            
            for (int i=0;i<map2.get(key2).size();i++) {
                System.out.println(map2.get(key2)[i]);  //prints everything in the array
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: A easier way to do that? there are some errors when i put that.

Comment: Can you define the errors? What are the error messages?

Comment: the error was present in the return type of the method I was invoking in getAllRecords ().I was putting HashMap rather than putting Hashmap <String, HashMap <Integer, ArrayList <Reservation> >>.In fact, it reported error in foreach loops because it didn't want a String but an Object. Then I managed to manage everything like this:

Comment: for(String Date: map.keySet()) {
            map.get(Date);
            HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Prenotazione>> map2= map.get(Date);
            for(Integer campo:map2.keySet()){
                System.out.println("----------------");
                for (int i=0;i<map2.get(campo).size();i++) {
                    Prenotazione p=map2.get(campo).get(i);
                    String classe=p.classe;
                    String slot=p.slot.toString();
                    System.out.println(Date+"<--->"+campo+"<--->"+classe+"<--->"+slot);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Much like yours.
In the ArrayList there is no .length () but size ().
Prenotazione is Reservation in Italy.

Comment: That was an error out of being too hastiness on my side.
I corrected it now. If this is the answer that helped you, you might want to mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Reservation>> map = new  HashMap<>();
```

You can print out all the reservations, sans map keys as follows.

```
map.values().stream()
       .flatMap(m->m.values().stream())
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .forEach(System.out::println); // prints each reservation
```

- the first stream, streams the inner map (values of the outer map)
- the flatMap replaces that stream with the stream of the inner values (the lists)
- the last flatMap streams the lists.

The above presumes that the Reservation class has overridden toString

If you want to print out all the keys too, you can do it like this.  I indented the output to provide a key/value hierarchy.

```
map.forEach((k,v)-> {
    System.out.println(k);
    v.forEach((k1,v1)-> {
         System.out.println("         " + k1);
         v1.forEach(res->System.out.println("              " + res));
    });
});
```

Comment: A easier way to do that?